# Como puedo escapar espacios en blanco en Rails en un string que ya tiene simbolos de escape?

Tags: string, ruby-on-rails, test

Estoy escribiendo unos tests en Rails que esperan un string como retorno.

Como el string es demasiado largo tengo que dividirlo en dos partes por cuestiones de estilo, lo cual hace que el test falle porque espera todos los espacios en blanco producto de dividir la línea en dos e indentarla.

```
    expected "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-link\"></span> accesoria de
                      376774879"
    actual "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-link\"></span> accesoria de 376774879"
```

He intentado de diferentes maneras cambiando el \ de lugar pero sin éxito. Por ejemplo:

```
  test "do something" do
    assert_equal "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-link\"></span> accesoria de\
                 #{orders(:attached_order).main_order.id}",
                 order_type_label(orders(:attached_order))
  end
```

En dònde deberían ir los simbolos de escape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el método `squish` para eliminar les espacios extras (incluyendo el salto de línea):

```
test "do something" do
  assert_equal "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-link\"></span> accesoria de\
               #{orders(:attached_order).main_order.id}".squish,
               order_type_label(orders(:attached_order))
end
```

También podrías considerar guardar el texto esperado en una variable y utilizarla para la comparación, creo que hace el código más legible; algo así:

```
test "do something" do
  expected = <<~TXT.squish
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span> accesoria de
    #{orders(:attached_order).main_order.id}
  TXT

  assert_equal expected, order_type_label(orders(:attached_order))
end
```

Al utilizar *HEREDOC* queda claro el texto que quieres comparar ya que no necesitas agregar caracteres de escape y el método `squish` está en otra línea.